# Porting AES class from Python 2.7 to 3.x+

Tags: python, python-3.x, aes, python-3.6

Hello any help porting this AES class from Python 2.7 to 3.6+ would be greatly appreciated.

I have a working copy in Python 2.7 below that I have implemented fine.

```
import hashlib
from Crypto import Random
from Crypto.Cipher import AES


class AESHandler:
    def __init__(self, cipherKey):
        hashedKey = hashlib.sha1(); hashedKey.update(cipherKey)
        self.pad = lambda self, s: s + (self.blockSize - len(s) % self.blockSize) * "\x00"
        self.unPad = lambda self, s : s.rstrip('\x00')
        self.toHex = lambda self, x:"".join([hex(ord(c))[2:].zfill(2) for c in x])
        self.blockSize = 16
        self.cipherKey = hashedKey.hexdigest()[:32]



    def aes_encrypt(self, stringIn):
        stringIn = self.pad(self, stringIn)
        initVector = Random.new().read(AES.block_size)
        cipher = AES.new(self.cipherKey, AES.MODE_CBC, initVector)
        return self.toHex(self, initVector + cipher.encrypt(stringIn))



    def aes_decrypt(self, stringIn):
        stringIn = (stringIn).decode("hex_codec")
        initVector = stringIn[:16]
        cipher = AES.new(self.cipherKey, AES.MODE_CBC, initVector)
        return self.unPad(self, cipher.decrypt(stringIn[16:]))



dataIn  = "Hello World!"
aesHandler = AESHandler("SUPER_SECRET_KEY")

encodedString = aesHandler.aes_encrypt(dataIn)
print("EncodedString: " + encodedString)

decodedString = aesHandler.aes_decrypt(encodedString)
print("DecodedString: " + decodedString)
```

The first problem as suspected when trying to run the class in Python 3.6 are encoding errors. So I applied UTF-8 encoding to the plain text string and cipher key, which then results in new errors.

## 1st Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "AESHandler.py", line 36, in <module>
    aesHandler = AESHandler("SUPER_SECRET_KEY")
  File "AESHandler.py", line 10, in __init__
    hashedKey = hashlib.sha1(); hashedKey.update(cipherKey)
TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing
```

At this point I added UTF-8 encoding to the plaintext string and cipher key to fix this problem which led to the next error.

## 2nd Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "AESHandler.py", line 38, in <module>
    encodedString = aesHandler.aes_encrypt(dataIn)
  File "AESHandler.py", line 20, in aes_encrypt
    stringIn = self.pad(self, stringIn)
  File "AESHandler.py", line 11, in <lambda>
    self.pad = lambda self, s: s + (self.blockSize - len(s) % self.blockSize) * "\x00"
TypeError: can't concat str to bytes
```

To fix this error I changed:

```
self.pad = lambda self, s: s + (self.blockSize - len(s) % self.blockSize) * "\x00"
```

Changed to:

```
self.pad = lambda self, s: s + ((self.blockSize - len(s) % self.blockSize) * "\x00").encode("UTF-8")
```

## 3rd Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "AESHandler.py", line 38, in <module>
    encodedString = aesHandler.aes_encrypt(dataIn)
  File "AESHandler.py", line 22, in aes_encrypt
    cipher = AES.new(self.cipherKey, AES.MODE_CBC, initVector)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/Crypto/Cipher/AES.py", line 232, in new
    return _create_cipher(sys.modules[__name__], key, mode, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/Crypto/Cipher/__init__.py", line 79, in _create_cipher
    return modes[mode](factory, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/Crypto/Cipher/_mode_cbc.py", line 274, in _create_cbc_cipher
    cipher_state = factory._create_base_cipher(kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/Crypto/Cipher/AES.py", line 103, in _create_base_cipher
    result = start_operation(c_uint8_ptr(key),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/Crypto/Util/_raw_api.py", line 145, in c_uint8_ptr
    raise TypeError("Object type %s cannot be passed to C code" % type(data))
TypeError: Object type <class 'str'> cannot be passed to C code
```

At this point I do not even understand the error very well or in what direction to go to fix this. Below I have left the updated source to this point. Any help to understand and fix this would be great, thanks!

```
import hashlib
from Crypto import Random
from Crypto.Cipher import AES


class AESHandler:
    def __init__(self, cipherKey):
        hashedKey = hashlib.sha1(); hashedKey.update(cipherKey)
        self.pad = lambda self, s: s + (self.blockSize - len(s) % self.blockSize) * "\x00"
        self.unPad = lambda self, s : s.rstrip('\x00')
        self.toHex = lambda self, x:"".join([hex(ord(c))[2:].zfill(2) for c in x])
        self.blockSize = 16
        self.cipherKey = hashedKey.hexdigest()[:32]



    def aes_encrypt(self, stringIn):
        stringIn = self.pad(self, stringIn)
        initVector = Random.new().read(AES.block_size)
        cipher = AES.new(self.cipherKey, AES.MODE_CBC, initVector)
        return self.toHex(self, initVector + cipher.encrypt(stringIn))



    def aes_decrypt(self, stringIn):
        stringIn = (stringIn).decode("hex_codec")
        initVector = stringIn[:16]
        cipher = AES.new(self.cipherKey, AES.MODE_CBC, initVector)
        return self.unPad(self, cipher.decrypt(stringIn[16:]))



dataIn  = "Hello World!"
aesHandler = AESHandler("SUPER_SECRET_KEY")

encodedString = aesHandler.aes_encrypt(dataIn)
print("EncodedString: " + encodedString)

decodedString = aesHandler.aes_decrypt(encodedString)
print("DecodedString: " + decodedString)
```

Comment: Essentially on your move to Python 3 you ported all your Py2 strings to Py3 strings. However, Py3 strings are essentially Py2 unicode. Py2 strings are closer to `bytes()`. Henve, I believe you should bring your strings to `bytes`.

Comment: It looks like your trying to port to python3 without understanding `bytes` objects. You will not be able to do so. Also, your padding method is not very robust as it will only work with a subset of plaintext.

Comment: Also you define a bunch of methods using `lambda`. I am not quite sure I am getting why not using the classical `def` construct.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick. Essentially, I forced all the internals to work on `bytes` when needed.

```
#!pip install pycrypto
import hashlib
import codecs
from Crypto import Random
from Crypto.Cipher import AES


class AESHandler:
    def __init__(self, cipherKey):
        hashedKey = hashlib.sha1(); hashedKey.update(cipherKey.encode())
        self.pad = lambda self, s: s + (self.blockSize - len(s) % self.blockSize) * b'\x00'
        self.unPad = lambda self, s : s.rstrip(b'\x00')
        self.toHex = lambda self, x: b"".join([hex(c)[2:].zfill(2).encode() for c in x])
        self.blockSize = 16
        self.cipherKey = hashedKey.hexdigest()[:32]

    def aes_encrypt(self, stringIn):
        stringIn = self.pad(self, stringIn.encode())
        initVector = Random.new().read(AES.block_size)
        cipher = AES.new(self.cipherKey, AES.MODE_CBC, initVector)
        return self.toHex(self, initVector + cipher.encrypt(stringIn))

    def aes_decrypt(self, stringIn):
        stringIn = codecs.decode(stringIn, "hex_codec")
        initVector = stringIn[:16]
        cipher = AES.new(self.cipherKey, AES.MODE_CBC, initVector)
        return self.unPad(self, cipher.decrypt(stringIn[16:])).decode()


dataIn  = "Hello World! α and ω"
aesHandler = AESHandler("SUPER_SECRET_KEY")

encodedString = aesHandler.aes_encrypt(dataIn)
print("EncodedString:", encodedString)
# EncodedString: b'e8b7621f04310fbb40bb40a22ccc4a62e67fa5124fee5bac858288615028b2519f30516bc84b9a4625c944b4a22f0599'

decodedString = aesHandler.aes_decrypt(encodedString)
print("DecodedString:", decodedString)
# DecodedString: Hello World! α and ω
```

(**EDITED** to fix `toHex()` not working with `bytes`)

Comment: Thanks I tried your changes, and still getting the same 3rd error: raise TypeError("Object type %s cannot be passed to C code" % type(data))

Comment: Thanks I tried it but it still was throwing the same error, but with some coffee this morning I got it working, left the working copy posted below. Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed now, there was still 2 strings that needed encoded. Thanks a lot for the help guys below I posted the final working copy.

```
import hashlib
import codecs
from Crypto import Random
from Crypto.Cipher import AES


class AESHandler:
    def __init__(self, cipherKey):
        hashedKey = hashlib.sha1(); hashedKey.update(cipherKey.encode())
        self.pad = lambda self, s: s + (self.blockSize - len(s) % self.blockSize) * b'\x00'
        self.unPad = lambda self, s : s.rstrip(b'\x00')
        self.toHex = lambda self, x: b"".join([hex(c)[2:].zfill(2).encode() for c in x])
        self.blockSize = 16
        self.cipherKey = hashedKey.hexdigest()[:32]

    def aes_encrypt(self, stringIn):
        stringIn = self.pad(self, stringIn.encode())
        initVector = Random.new().read(AES.block_size)
        cipher = AES.new(self.cipherKey.encode(), AES.MODE_CBC, initVector)
        return self.toHex(self, initVector + cipher.encrypt(stringIn))

    def aes_decrypt(self, stringIn):
        stringIn = codecs.decode(stringIn, "hex_codec")
        initVector = stringIn[:16]
        cipher = AES.new(self.cipherKey.encode(), AES.MODE_CBC, initVector)
        return self.unPad(self, cipher.decrypt(stringIn[16:])).decode()


dataIn  = "Hello World!"
aesHandler = AESHandler("SUPER_SECRET_KEY")

encodedString = aesHandler.aes_encrypt(dataIn)
print("EncodedString:", encodedString)

decodedString = aesHandler.aes_decrypt(encodedString)
print("DecodedString:", decodedString)
```